# How to query the Human Microbiome Project (HMP) to find all subjects with both 16s and WGS workups?

Tags: public-databases, genomics, data-download, metagenome

I am looking for a query to run on [the HMP database](https://portal.hmpdacc.org/query/s) that will return all subjects who have had BOTH 16s *and* whole genomes sequence (WGS) workups.  I am currently using this query...

```
file.matrix_type = 16s_community OR file.matrix_type = wgs_community AND (file.format = FASTA OR file.format = FASTQ)
```

and sifting through the results by adding them to my shopping cart, browsing the file types until I have added all of the samples from one subject, and then I check to see if I have at least one 16s and one WGS.  So far, I have not found one person who has had both 16s and WGS where both files were publicly accessible, and most do not have WGS at all.  There must be a way to get subjects with both workups done to make this faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a few different queries, I don't believe there is a more specific one than this and I found that by searching and clicking through all of the results given by this query that eventually I found patients that fit the criteria of having both WGS and 16s.